# Difference from using Option Stores than Setup Stores in Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Is there any difference from using Option Stores than Setup Stores behind?

I can use the two versions below in Vue 3 and would like to know if behind there is any difference or just the writing?

// Option Stores

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', {
  state: () => ({ count: 0, name: 'Eduardo' }),
  getters: {
    doubleCount: (state) => state.count * 2,
  },
  actions: {
    increment() {
      this.count++
    },
  },
})
```

// Setup Stores

```
export const useCounterStore = defineStore('counter', () => {
  const count = ref(0)
  const name = ref('Eduardo')
  const doubleCount = computed(() => count.value * 2)
  function increment() {
    count.value++
  }

  return { count, name, doubleCount, increment }
})
```

Comment: No difference performance wise.  In choosing which syntax to use, the docs answer the question with "pick the one that you feel the most comfortable with".  Setup stores are a bit more flexible though, allowing watchers and free use of any composable.